# How can I add r.local.relief to the QGIS Processing Toolbox?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm working with QGIS 2.12 and GRASS 7.0.3RC1. I'm making a model using the model builder and trying to add the GRASS addon "r.local.relief" in my QGIS model, but the addon does not show up in the Processing Toolbox of QGIS. The addon installs sucessfully, and the file for it is shown in the folder with the other GRASS tools as a '*.bat' file (the other files are '*.exe'). Is there anyway that this tool can be added to the processing toolbox of QGIS 2.12 to be used on the model builder?
I've searched all afternoon but I can't seem to find any pages on the integration of that tool on QGIS, only on the use of it in the GRASS GUI.

[image: Printscreen of QGIS' Model Builder and GRASS Tools Folder]

Comment: New and related development: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/319333/5256

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[r.local.relief](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.local.relief.html) is an addon and not a standard Grass command. It is a Python script ([r.local.relief.py](https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7/raster/r.local.relief/r.local.relief.py)) using `grass.script`, however it is not installed by default.

1. you need first to install the addon in GRASS GIS
2. and after create a processing algorithm to use this new Grass command.

The processing Python module use the Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to execute the original GRASS commands

In the /.../processing/algs/grass7 there is a text file (grass7.txt) which explains the procedure ("A short guide for creating and editing GRASS GIS 7 algorithms")

In the /.../processing/algs/exampleprovider folder there is an example plugin to  add algorithms to Processing..